# Fire a GET request and get the node Stream

Tags: node.js, node-request

I'm trying to send as `formData`, a stream from an image I get using [request](https://github.com/request/request)

The problem is that the request is fire after the `formData` request.
Is there any way I can pipe the image request to recognize? but with the freedom of adding parameters to the `formData`?

e.g:

```
var req = request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://www.foo.bar/api/v1/tag/recognize',
  formData: {
    image_file: request('http://visual-recognition-demo.mybluemix.net/images/horses.jpg'),
    param2: 'value2'
  },
  json: true,
});
```

How do I fire:

`request('http://visual-recognition-demo.mybluemix.net/images/horses.jpg')`

so the response can be used in `req`

**UPDATE:** Seems like the `Content-Length` header is missing in the
http://visual-recognition-demo.mybluemix.net/images/horses.jpg response
and you only get `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

More details [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/nodejs-wrapper/issues/4)

Comment: I'm not sure that the `request` library would allow you to this via piping but instead you'd just have to use a callback with the body returned from the original request.

Comment: I think this should be handle in the request library. It happens when you don't specify `content-length` in the first response

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look [this part](https://github.com/request/request#streaming) of the docs.  What you're describing is essentially this block

```
request.get('http://google.com/img.png').pipe(request.put('some_url'));
```

Note the docs

> When doing so, content-type and content-length are preserved in the
>   PUT headers.

Also note, request will always return a Stream if you don't specify a callback.  If you do provide a callback it tries to convert the response to a String.  Use the `encoding:null` to get it to return raw bytes.
Example -

```
request({
   url: 'some_url', //your image
   encoding: null  //returns resp.body as bytes
}, callback..)
```

To chain calls together (run one after the other) , you can nest the callbacks or use promises.  For example to run a request after another request completes -

```
var request = require('request');

//1st
request('first_url', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

      //2nd
      request('other_url', function (error, response, body) {   
         //process resp
      });
  }
});
```

Or even better, convert the request callback code to Promises.  [See a promise library like Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) on how to do this.

Here's an example with bluebird (uses then to work in an iterative fasion)

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"));

request.getAsync('some_url').then(function(resp) {
   request.getAsync('some_other_url').then(..processing code..);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples and the explanation. If you look at [visual recognition](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/nodejs-wrapper/blob/master/services/visual_recognition/v1.js#L67) service implementation. How do you think I can implement your solution?  
I want to hide from users the problem of chaining calls. They should use the snippet I'm using for this question.

Comment: If you want the users to be able to pipe in a binary object from an ajax request (say request lib or whatever), you would need to do a refactor of the actual implementation logic of how params is used. You should also (my suggestion) make the usage of a piped in resource be very explicit in the docs.  Just taking a glance at your library I would never expect to be able to use an asynchronous response as a parameter (regardless if it was raw bytes or not)

Comment: Basically I just provided an answer of how to chain a promise (using bytes or text response), so you can implement yourself.  The above answer explains the process using the request library.  But ideally I would think you wouldn't allow a response to be input as a parameter; or if you do, update the docs to very clearly show that option.

Comment: Try playing around with - `request({url: 'http://visual-recognition-demo.mybluemix.net/images/horses.jpg', encoding: null})`

Comment: @GermanAttanasioRuiz Np, follow me on github if you'd like.  Will be putting alot of good examples of Node code continually throughout the year :)

Comment: Thank you! I was providing a callback and was hitting the 500MB string size limit in node. Adding `encoding:null` solved my problem